# Correct SMTP Url for Gmail in Bottle Cork?

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, settings, bottle

For using Bottle Cork smtp_url is needed. I want to use my Gmail account for sending email. I've tryed many variants of this, from "smtp://smtp.gmail.com" to "smtp://smtp.gmail.com", nothing works. Maybe somebody knows the correct settings?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a very large range of variants you've tried... nevertheless, what kind of errors are you getting? And can you show some code.

Comment: `smtp.gmail.com:587`?

Comment: smtp.gmail.com:587 - no, error:SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. s15sm448454lbp.42 - gsmtp', '<username>@gmail.com')

Comment: `starttls://username:password@smtp.gmail.com:587`?

Comment: Closer! starttls://username:password@smtp.gmail.com:587
SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at\n5.7.9 http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833 dq7sm204221lac.32 - gsmtp')

Comment: did you create the app password? You did include a username etc..#

Comment: Oh... yeah, there was a little mistake in password :( Now works correctly with starttls://username:password@smtp.gmail.com:587, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer was posted in the comments, thanks to @Padraic:
The `smtp_url` argument in the `cork.cork.Mailer` or `cork.Cork()` configuration should be set to `starttls://username:password@smtp.gmail.com:587`, as in:

```py
mailer = cork.cork.Mailer(sender='yourgmail@gmail.com',smtp_url='starttls://yourgmail:YourPassword@smtp.gmail.com:587')
mailer.send_email(email_addr='otherperson@example.com', subject='You have mail', email_text='Your email text')
```

You might need to [allow "less secure apps" in GMail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255), in order for your process to get access.